# Unzip Files To Full Path using BAT file

Tags: batch-file

I am having trouble with a BAT file it will not extract the files to their full path name as some of the zip files contain files called the same name but with different sales data contained within them

example files

```
 MainLine20140606.zip contains marketingdb.mdb
 Valis20140606.zip contains marketingdb.mdb
```

I don't want these to over write each other but don't want to have to manually intervene either.

The BAT file unzips any zip files in the folder it is run from:

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%I IN (' dir /b /s /a-d *.zip ') DO (
    "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" x -y -o"%%~dpI\%%~fI" "%%I" 
)
pause
```

Comment: There is something not clear: Do you want to extract each zip file inside a separate folder with the name of the zip file or what you need is to extract all the files in the same folder with the output files renamed?

Comment: Either solution you have suggested would work I have to either extract the mdb's out and rename them with the zip folders name and the mdb name or extract them into separate folders eached named after the zip file containing its mdb that way do not have to rename them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    set "rarCmd=%programFiles%\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe"

    for /r "%cd%" %%a in (*.zip) do "%rarCmd%" x -or -y "%%~fa" * "%~dp0%%~na\"

    endlocal
```

For each zip file under the current folder (`/r "%cd%"`) , call winrar to extract (`x`), with automatic renaming (`-or`) if needed, assuming yes to all queries (`-y`), the zip file (`%%~fa`, that is, the file with full path), selecting all the file contents (`*`) and placing the output in a folder with the same name that the zip (`%%~na`) under the folder where the batch file is placed (`%~dp0`)

The `-or` is included to not overwrite the files from previous runs, remove it if not needed.

The name of the target folder can be also indicated adding the `-ad` switch and removing the `%%~na\` from the target folder in command.

Comment: Absolutely superb your spot on exactly how I wanted it to be thank you so much massive cudos :) ill repost link to this answer in other forums thank you again

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command

```
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" e -ad "Path To\ZIP Files\*.zip" "Path To\Target\Folder\"
```

With this command **WinRAR** decompresses all *.zip in `Path To\ZIP Files\` to `Path To\Target\Folder\` whereby for each ZIP file the name of the ZIP file is appended to the target directory path.

After **WinRAR** finished decompressing all ZIP files, you can run following batch file to move all `marketingdb.mdb` in all created subfolders to original target folder with renaming the MDB files and delete the now empty subfolders.

```
@echo off
cd /D "Path To\Target\Folder\"
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir * /b /ad') do (
   move "%%I\marketingdb.mdb" "%%I.mdb"
   rd "%%I"
)
```

Comment: This was a very good effort but I kept getting errors when trying to use it, thank you so much for your answer though very much appreciated :)

Comment: @LoveToys, would you please let me know which errors you get on execution of **WinRAR** or the batch file? I tried both with 2 ZIP files each containing only `marketingdb.mdb` according to your question and no error occurred on execution of **WinRAR** or the batch file. Are your ZIP files containing more than just `marketingdb.mdb`?

Comment: Yes there was one database called TDmarketingdb.accdb, but it wasnt that which was the error it was not extracting or creating folders with the zip filename and it was not extracting I had to manually point to folder and file, so was unable to automate.